# Custom click on Ionic notification using Firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been using ionic and FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) for notification.

I get the notification on my app and now I have 2 issues. First, if its a normal notification like not with advanced options in *Firebase Console > Notification*, then it doesn't play any sound, but when it's data Notification, then it does play a sound. Second, I want to open a particular page of my app on notification click.

So how do I do that?

**Note**: I am using ionic not an ionic2.

Answer (score 3):

First issue:
We have sound in both situations. Have you tried to send an empty data object?

Second issue:
Just assuming you use the Cordova FCM plugin. Otherwise install it with

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm --save
```

Use the data with an ID to the right datapage and then do something like:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if(window.cordova) {
            FCMPlugin.onNotification(
                function(data){
                    if(data.wasTapped){
                        //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
                        $state.go('yourpage', {id:data.pageId});
                        console.log('onNotification tapped true');
                    } else {
                        //Notification was received in foreground. User needs to be notified.
                        console.log('onNotification tapped false');
                    }
                },
                function(msg){
                    console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
                },
                function(err){
                    console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ohk so where should i keep this code into the app.js file ?

Comment: For example within `.run` and always after latform is ready. I edited my answer with this.

Comment: @jack_007 You can add them as key/value pairs in the advanced options tab of the *Firebase Console > Notifications* page. For example *pageId* as value and *876* as key. Or from an webservice add `"data": {"pageId": "876"}` to your request data. Of course the choice of key name and value is up to you.

Comment: @jack_007 And data.wasTapped will be set by the plugin. And typing this, I realize that I probably assumed you used the Cordova FCM plugin, but that might not be the case. I will add this to my answer.

Comment: @janP in my case i m always receiving data.wasTapped= false

Comment: @Sakshi Hard to tell from here what the problem might be. It should be set to true upon tapping the notification. Try a console log on JSON.stringify(data). Maybe that gives some clarification.