# Ionic notification in android

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, push-notification

I used blow code for ionic notification I have used fcm (firebase cloud messaging)

I Received push Notifications when the app is close but I didn't receive notification when the app is open(running) in android

> app.js

```
.config(function($ionicCloudProvider) {
    $ionicCloudProvider.init({
    "core": {
      "app_id": "xxxxxx"
    },
    "push": {
      "sender_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "pluginConfig": {
        "ios": {
          "badge": true,
          "sound": true
        },
        "android": {
            "badge": true,
          "iconColor": "#343434"
        }
      }
    }
  });

})
```

> controler.js

```
$ionicPush.register().then(function(t) {
            return $ionicPush.saveToken(t);
          }).then(function(t) {
            console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
            alert(t.token);
          });

$rootScope.$on('cloud:push:notification', function(data) {
    console.log("dbhfd")
        var msg = data.message;
    console.log("dbhfd")
        alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
        $state.go('message');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use localnotification when new notification received in the foreground

```
    this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
      if(data.wasTapped){
        console.log("Received in background");
      } else {
        console.log("Received in foreground");
          this.localNotifications.schedule({
           id: 1,
           title: ""+data.title+"",
           text: ""+data.body+""
        });
      };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

hi, 
when the app is opened you will not get any notifications even you can check with Facebook or any other apps.if app is closed then only you will receive notifications that's not an issue i think you achieved your goal

Comment: That's not true. Even Facebook app receives notifications when opened. They will not show up in the status bar, but actually are received as you get badges in the header of the app. Notifications are a perfect way to make the app respond on new content without having to poll every few seconds/minutes for new content.

Comment: actully i m working in chat application. How to update ui when app is open?

Comment: cloud:push:notification method does not fired.

Comment: @Sakshi I'm not familiar with Ionic Push, but I use cordova-plugin-fcm and am able to get notifications with the app in foreground. Have a look at https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm, header *Receiving push notification data*

Comment: @JanP i have installed app.js:48 Uncaught ReferenceError: FCMPlugin is not defined but got error  Uncaught ReferenceError: FCMPlugin is not defined.

Comment: @Sakshi I guess you get this error when serving the app in a browser? Then wrap it up with `if (window.cordova) {...}` and make sure platform is ready.

Comment: .run(function($ionicPlatform,$ionicPush) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    FCMPlugin.onNotification(
  function(data){
    if(data.wasTapped){
      //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
      alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
    }else{
      alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
    }
  },
  function(msg){
    console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
  },
  function(err){
    console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
  }
);

   
  }

);
})

Comment: @Sakshi Please have a look at my answer in this question. It has the example code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41179411/3975709

Comment: @JanP hey now  i have received notification when app is open but how can alert  message in my app when app is open?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131336/discussion-between-janp-and-sakshi).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate with firebase + push notifications then you can follow this link
[here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://enappd.com/blog/firebase-push-notification-in-ionic-react-capacitor/111/&ved=2ahUKEwi4ubPzrZb2AhXU7HMBHZM6AxoQFnoECCUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw216rntLf5pqAg0cWoXypjU)!
And in this push notifications link just keep **register() function & related code in App.tsx** then you will get notifications foreground and background.

And if you want to produce local notifications then follow this link [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://enappd.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ionic-5-capacitor/132/&ved=2ahUKEwi4ubPzrZb2AhXU7HMBHZM6AxoQFnoECDYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0qAg_cAPY4t1a1lJ8Ny2Mc)!